# How to sort lines of a hash in descending order according to one of the key-value pairs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have the following hash:

```
lines[0] = {"a" => dog, "b" => 32, "c" =>555, "d" => 100}
lines[1] = {"a" => cat, "b" => 34, "c" =>554, "d" => 4542}
lines[2] = {"a" => bird, "b" => 31, "c" =>532435, "d" => 23}
```

I would like to sort the hash by "b" in descending order so that I end up with:

```
lines[0] = {"a" => cat, "b" => 34, "c" =>554, "d" => 4542}
lines[1] = {"a" => dog, "b" => 32, "c" =>555, "d" => 100}
lines[2] = {"a" => bird, "b" => 31, "c" =>532435, "d" => 23}
```

What would be the best way to achieve that? Is there a method in Ruby that does this for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a **peculiar** case where lines is NOT an array but a Hash, so you want to reassign values for each key based on value's order, for that first create array out of Hash, sort that, and that create a Hash based on new index e.g.

```
lines = {}
lines[0] = {"a" => :dog, "b" => 32, "c" =>555, "d" => 100}
lines[1] = {"a" => :cat, "b" => 34, "c" =>554, "d" => 4542}
lines[2] = {"a" => :bird, "b" => 31, "c" =>532435, "d" => 23}

require 'pp'
pp Hash[lines.map.sort_by {|k,v| -v["b"]}.map.with_index {|v, index| [index, v[1]]}]
```

output is:

```
{0=>{"a"=>:cat, "b"=>34, "c"=>554, "d"=>4542},
 1=>{"a"=>:dog, "b"=>32, "c"=>555, "d"=>100},
 2=>{"a"=>:bird, "b"=>31, "c"=>532435, "d"=>23}}
```

That said, why lines is a Hash? it could better be represented by an Array

Comment: lines is a Hash because I am carrying that data over from a previous script and other than the sort it was much easier to manipulate the date. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
lines.sort_by! {|hash| -hash["b"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
lines.sort! { |a, b| b["b"] <=> a["b"] }
```

Comment: I get the following error: undefined method 'sort!' for #<Hash:0x3164d18> (NoMethodError)

Comment: @walterfaye There is 2 options: - You lied in your question. - You did not use my code correctly. Be sure you do `lines.sort` and not `lines[0].sort`. You want to sort the array `lines`, not its hashes `lines[n]`.